# How to compare hash map key dynamically inside the closure in Grails?

Tags: java, grails, gsp

Here I have hash map passed from the controller to GSP page.

Controller:

`Map<String, List<String>> nameFiles = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();`

```
  nameFiles.put('patient1',["AA","BB","CC"]);
  nameFiles.put('patient2',["DD","EE","FF"]);
```

`model.put("nameFiles", nameFiles);`

GSP page:

`var patient = getPatient();` // lets say we get random patient through some jQuery function, could be not available in the nameFiles key

```
//check If nameFiles contain key same as patient varaible 
 <% nameFiles.each { fm -> %>
    <% if (fm.containsKey(patient)) { %> // This if statement cannot compare dynamic sting varaaible. How to do this.
        alert("Yes nameFiles contain the patient");
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery code. "does not work" isn't a very good description of the problem. Are you getting errors, or seeing some wrong output? Please be more detailed.

Comment: I do have key element called randomName in the NameFiles Hashmap so when                                             <% if(fm.containsKey(patientIdentifier)) { %> 
alert("YES");

 <% } %>                                 I should suppose to see YES popup message, but i don't see it

Comment: @RenéScheibe: I approved your edit, but your naming convention correction properly belongs in your answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply but in my case i get patient from function and then check if this patient is in the nameFiles key. I have changed little bit in my question, please let me know if this makes more clear

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. The values of `nameFiles` are declared as `List<String>` but the values you add are actually of type `Map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have :

```
  Map<String, List<String>> nameFiles = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            nameFiles.put('patient1',[id:1,name:'Fred'])
            nameFiles.put('patient2',[id:2,name:'Tom'])
```

It is as simple as this to get current patient:

```
    <% def aa = nameFiles?.find{it.key=='patient1'}?.value %>
      <g:if test="${aa}">
        //  we definitely have ${aa} and it has been made null safe 
      <g:if>
```

This returns `{id:1, Name:Fred}` on gsp which is the list iteration

My goodness all that else if it is as if you are in a controller, I understand why you are having to do this but it isn't good practice you could just create a tagLib that takes current value and processes the entry according to something in a given list or maybe against db fresh on the fly all correctly presented produced.

Final edit whilst you can declare variables like jsp you can also use

```
<g:set var="aa" value="${nameFiles?.find{it.key=='patient1'}?.value}" scope="page|session|..."/>
```

By default variable is set for the page but could be made into a session variable either way it is a lot cleaner than `<% %>`

**Hopefully final edit**

I think people should think carefully about what their actual problem is and try to present the problem clearly otherwise the audience ends up answering something else due to the poor quality of the post.

If I understand correctly you have something happening in a controller as in some list being produced. The missing bit must be you are then doing some form of form check maybe a select box selection that then ends up in `jquery` by that you mean you have some form of java script check going on against a form field check.

There are two ways of pumping such information into the javascript world for such purposes

Method 1:

```
//I haven't tested this, hopefully gives you the idea
var array = []
<g:each in="${namedFiles}" var="${pa}">
    array.push({code:'${pa.key} listing:'${pa.value}'})
</g:each>
```

Method 2
Controller

```
 //where you now push named files as a json  
  return [namedFiles as JSON].toString()

  // or alternatively in gsp javascript segment something like this
  var results=$.parseJSON('<%=namedFiles.encodeAsJSON()%>');
  var results = results['patient1']
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but in my case i get patient from function and then check if this patient is in the nameFiles key. I have changed little bit in my question, please let me know if this makes more clear

Comment: Not at all you have started the question about maps containing string list from controller to gsp. You then updated to talk about jquery and your question talks of grails gsp iteration whilst you twisted it about jquery . Jquery results need to be dealt with using java script

Answer (score 0):

**Variable Declaration in GSP**

You can declare variables within `<% %>` brackets:

```
<% patientIdentifier = 'randomName' %>
```

For more details see the Grails documentation on [Variables and Scopes](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#variablesAndScopes).

**Checking if Patient is contained in namedFiles**

You don't need to iterate over the map. Just checking the map if it contains the key.

```
// check if nameFiles contains key same as patient variable
<% if (nameFiles.containsKey(patient)) { %>
    alert("Yes nameFiles contains the patient");
<% } %>
```

Comment: I know to declare variables with <% %> brackets but in my case, i cannot do this.

Comment: Then please provide more details in your question about this.

Comment: I have added more detail, please let me know if this makes more clear

Answer (score 0):

Honestly speaking I didn't get what are you asking and what kind of problem do you have as a result, but I guess that you tried to implement something like that:

```
<g:if test="${nameFiles[patient]}">
    alert("Yes nameFiles contain the patient");
</g:if>
```

As you may be noticed I tried to avoid the scriptlet mess and used grails custom tags.

Also I hardly imagine how are you going to call the jQuery function to get a variable and then use it for generating a view on the server side. But try to define some mock "patient" variable at first to test my sample.

If the "patient" variable value is only available at the client side - so you have to change the approach and generate your alerts not on the server.

UPD
From the other hand you could return your nameFiles as JSON in your controller and then parse this JSON with javascript on the client side like that:

```
var nameFiles = JSON.parse("${nameFiles}")

if (nameFiles.hasOwnProperty(patient)) {
    alert("Yes nameFiles contain the patient");
}
```

I haven't test this code, but at least you are pointed that gsp are rendered on server and you can convert your map to JSON, pass it to the view, parse with JavaScript and generate the needed alert.